# Vb conncetion string to Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, vbscript

How will look connection string to Oracle db if I have such parameters:

```
HOST = host  
PORT = 1531
SERVICE_NAME = service_name
User: USER_ADMIN
pass: USER_ADMIN
```

Now I have connection string like this:

```
set oConn =  CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
 oConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=host/orcl;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=password;Unicode=True;Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};"
oConn.Open
```

Correct me please!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you have an error? What's the TNSNAME of your database and what's the version of your Microsoft Oracle driver? Anyway the answer is probably [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection string is wrong, you cannot use `Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle` and `Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}` at the same time.

In case you like to use the Oracle OLE DB provider try this:

```
Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.provider = "OraOLEDB.Oracle"
DB = host & ":" & port & "/" & SERVICE_NAME
oConn.Open "Data Source=DB", User, pass
```

which should be equivalent to:

```
Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
DB = host & ":" & port & "/" & SERVICE_NAME
oConn.Open "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=DB;User Id=" & User & ";Password=" & pass
```

However, I do not know whether Oracle OLE DB supports [Easy Connect Naming Method](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/network.112/e10836/naming.htm#i498306) (EZ), I never used it. In case it does not support EZ try this one instead:

```
DB = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=" & host & ")(PORT=" & port & "))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=" & SERVICE_NAME & ")))"
```

Actually such definition should be written in `tnsnames.ora` file, e.g.

```
DB_TNS.your.domain = 
  (DESCRIPTION= 
    (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host)(PORT=1531))
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVICE_NAME=service_name)
      (SERVER=server)
      (INSTANCE_NAME=instance_name)
    )
  )
```

Then you can simply use `oConn.Open "Data Source=DB_TNS", User, pass`

In case you prefer to use the ODBC driver (although the ODBC driver from Microsoft is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) use this one: [ADO ConnectionStings](http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=90#ODBCDriverForOracleFromMicrosoft)